# Fastest way to earn coins?

Tags: pixel-gun-3d

In Pixel Gun 3D, I have trouble getting coins, because when i join a team battle, the most I get is about 5 coins. Is there a faster way to get coins? Which game mode rewards you with the most coins per match?

Answer (score 2):

Here are my personal favorite ways to get coins:

### No.1: Watch free currency

It's right there in the lobby. Watch them daily!! For 5 ads every 12 hours you can get 45 coins and 30 gems. So if you watch them daily for 30 days, you get **1,350 coins and 900 gems!** Watch them with volume turned off for best experience! It helps me *so* much.

### No.2: Just play the game as usual

Back in 2014 getting coins was a tedious process. Now it feels as if you can get 100 in a day without even noticing. There's VIP, Battle Pass, Black Market, Set events, and so on.

Of course do the battle pass! Do challenges. Level up. Get coins and stuff. And so on. And if you do 34 daily challenges you get 300 coins!

Set events are also easy to take advantage of as well. Back when I was a noob I would block all the parts and only get 10 coins or VIP ~90% of the time. And even *that* wasn't any good because I wasn't getting any weapon parts (I doubted they were possible to get) and VIP at that time barely got you even 10 coins. Now I actually manage to get the event guns, as well as a fair amount of coins. In fact sometimes I'm really hungry for parts, I spin the raffle but end up with **only coins!** I'm really angry but when I turn back and see how much I got I'm actually pretty satisfied. So if you don't beg for them, *you'll get enough.*

As I said before, the reworked VIP is better than it used to be. For every match it gives you +10 coins, +10 battle credits, and +5 keys regardless of whether you win! It really helps me grind keys and other stuff.

And then there's Black Market. It's in the Buildings section of your current clan. However this is probably the least likely way to help yourself to some coins. That's because you have to give up some other currency, like gems or silver (you can't even do the other way around, but [they have their reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTscO.jpg)).  <del>Typically I don't go down this route unless I'm super desperate. If anything, the only good deal they have there is the 2200 battle credits pack for 190 gems. I've been lucky to afford it when it appeared.</del>  Actually, *it isn't **that** bad.* If you purchase the last two offers on the right side of the page like a wall, a new page will open. The amount of possible pages depends on the clan's fort power. For each new page you open you get a little prize as well (i.e. first one is merchant shovel). The last one, which is the 5th stage (requires ~15k fort power ), is a mythical primary called the **Treasurer**, it has a coin drop chance (higher than the Mayor Trophy Revolver, which seems to have none at all lol), it'll really help you! You'll have to sacrifice a lot of currency, but then it will pay off with [good offers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSt9G.jpg)! And if you leave the clan, rejoin it, or go to new one the progress is saved and carried! Also the quality of the offers apparently depends on your clan's position in the war (at the time of the photo my clan was in 4th place so I don't even think that's true). Anyways...

### No.3: Grind in clan war

It's really easy (if you're not farming the black market of course)! All you have to do is open the war map, scroll for an easy task, pick a suitable loadout and complete it! Then when you finish it, continue doing more while you can. Just pick the easy tasks, i.e. to kill players with certain weapon and capture points (leave the hard ones for your other clanmates). Those are typically the best tasks. The wall break with sniper tasks are also pretty straightforward. You just go to an unlikely part of the map, wait for the X-ray module to charge on your sniper, and then shoot everyone while you can! I haven't exactly tried that yet but it does seem viable. Even if that won't do, then just get the X-Ray glasses. They should last long enough.

That gets you a ***lot*** of silver, but for what? For the best part.

If you save up 45K silver and open it on 3 mega chests you immediately get the super chest! You also get 1K coins and a whole ton of clan weapon parts! Heck, wait for a clan chest point booster and then get **two** super chests instead of one! 45K looks like a pain in the neck, but it is definitely possible to get.  This method actually helps get clan weapons faster! That's because when the game gets you parts for clan weapons, it gives you parts for weapons you have the least parts for. But the super chest tries its best to do the opposite! Its also basically a free mega chest!

Oh, I almost forgot!

### No.4: Join the giveaways!!

I'm not joking. The devs ocasionally make giveaways in [their discord](https://discord.com/invite/pixelgun3d). It's not too hard. They also have weapon contests (which also get you currencies, of course), update spoilers, and many other fun things.

#### Bad ideas, in my opinion

Minigames are very slow to get coins. Arena gives you **only one coin** for every wave, yet each wave takes two minutes to finish. Who wants that?

Speed run is also the same thing. Every 1000 meters you get one coin, however each 1000 meters takes about a minute. I understand that your speed increases when you go farther, but *what if you fall off?* It's not very interesting method in my opinion.

<del>Lucky chest shouldn't be pushed to it's limits. Just open it when it's free, get 5 coins or 1 gem, and that's about it. If you try to keep blowing gems on it to get even more then the game will **scam you** and bombard you with weapon parts for trash weapons that are obsolete.  Don't try it.</del> **RIP lucky chest,** was removed in 21.6 update due to "unpopularity". Really? [People were still relying on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnzeT.png)

Don't beg people for in-game boosters. It's possible to gift people in the game, however even that requires *paying*. And you'll irritate everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I say do [Survival](http://pixel-gun-3d.wikia.com/wiki/Survival) mode.  That helped me the most. And when you do that walk in a circle and kill the creatures! That helped me the most to level and get coins easy.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you play at least once of every gamemode once a day and win so you get double rewards and XP, when you level up you get some coins and gems more as you level up. Also spend 270 coins to make a gem creator you get one gem a day then make a coin maker to get 3 coins a day for a cost of 85 gems. Also play a lot of arena rounds to get money

Answer (score 0):

What I do is play every single gamemode for x2 reward and play campaign. You get 2 times more experience **and** coins. Also, play arena. Get the lucky chests and open novice chests. They give 10 coins if you land on it, which is a pretty high possibility.  Also spend 270 coins to make a gem creator you get one gem a day then make a coin maker to get 3 coins a day for a cost of 85 gems. They will earn you a fortune someday.

Answer (score -1):

There are over 7+ ways you get coins, here is  a [video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=o3cjNLxptng) on the best ways (no hacks, because a lot of websites mention using cheats) to get coins...

1. **Chests.**
   Chests in the game have a chance of coins inside, and you can earn 10 - 250 depending on how many times you spin it.
2. **Battle Pass Rewards.**
   Completing battle pass quests gain access to rewards, and coins are guaranteed collectable.
3. **Ads.**
   Might sound like a cash grab, but the game gives you 10 - 50 coins for just watching 30 second ads, to gems.

> As mentioned earlier, the cheat scamming won't get you anywhere, it is just an upsell and just warning you that you shouldn't use it, especially with the "no human verification" sign.

Answer (score -5):

I used lucky chests to farm 1.60 million money